# Uncaught Error: Unexpected pipe 'CutDescriptionPipe' imported by the module 'SharedModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular2, pipes

Как подключить пайпы к модулю.
При такой реализации выдает ошибку.

// shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CutDescriptionPipe } from 'src/app/shared/cut- 
description.pipe';
import { SearchPipe } from 'src/app/shared/search.pipe';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CutDescriptionPipe,
        SearchPipe],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        CutDescriptionPipe,
        SearchPipe
    ],
    exports: [
        CutDescriptionPipe,
        SearchPipe
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

//  film-сatalog.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { FilmsListComponent } from './films-list/films-list.component';

import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { FilmItemComponent } from './film-item/film-item.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SerchComponent } from './serch/serch.component';
import { ActorItemComponent } from './actor-item/actor-item.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MainComponent, 
    FilmItemComponent, 
    FilmsListComponent, 
    SerchComponent, 
    ActorItemComponent
  ]
})
export class FilmCatalogModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите `CutDescriptionPipe, SearchPipe` из `imports`. В `imports` Вы можете только указывать модули, которые экспортируют директивы/компоненты/пайпы, для того чтобы они были доступны в текущем модуле.